AGOL Arcade Expression to change symbology color and shape
I want to use an Arcade expression in ArcGIS Online to assign a symbol and a color to different attributes. For example, if the attribute value is 'yes,' the symbol is round and green. If the attribute value is 'no,' the Symbol is square and red.
Is it possible to do all this - assign the colors AND shapes -  in an arcade symbology expression?

You don't need any arcade to do that, just symbolise your data with unique values.

Long story short - No.
The arcade expression window in the Map Viewer editor is simply for producing values in which you can symbolize on but does not actually define the symbology for these values (shape and color).
You can accomplish programmatic manipulation of the symbology expression and style using the ArcGIS API For Python though. https://developers.arcgis.com/python/latest/guide/advanced-cartography-part1/
